# Excel VBA code doesn't work in Open Office (Code copy files from list)

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I had some excel VBA code, and it doesn't work in Open Office Calc.
Code in excel copy files from list from different catalog to another.

I don't know macro programming in open office. I read about diffrent declaration, but it really hard for me. What should I change for open office?
I will really grateful for any help.

Sub copyfiles()

```
Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
Dim xSFileDlg As FileDialog, xDFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xSPathStr As Variant, xDPathStr As Variant
Dim xVal As String
On Error Resume Next
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Wybierz pliki do skopiowania:", "KuTools For Excel", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set xSFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xSFileDlg.Title = "Wybierz folder z którego kopiuję:"
If xSFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xSPathStr = xSFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xDFileDlg.Title = "Wybierz folder do którego kopiuję:"
If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xDPathStr = xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
For Each xCell In xRg
    xVal = xCell.Value
    If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
        FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & xVal
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to be entirely rewritten. OpenOffice Basic is a completely different programming platform from MS Office VBA.

One good place to start learning OpenOffice Basic is http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php.